# Specify YouTube Channel Id to Upload Video

Tags: google-apps-script, upload, youtube-api

I am using this Apps Script code to upload videos from Google Drive to my YouTube channel, which works fine.

I have created another channel under my Google account and want to upload videos to this second channel. How do I specify the ID of the second channel in the code?

Because when using the code and specifying the second channel with:

```
id=CHANNEL_ID
```

The code still uploads the video to the first channel (which is created by default with a Google account).

---

I also note that an authorization window appears the first time the code is executed. But it allows authorization only through a Google account. If you try to choose authorization through the second YouTube channel - it will give an error:

```
function uploadToYoutube(){ 
  const sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(" ").getBlob();
  const videoResource = { 
    snippet: {
      title: 'Summer vacation in California', 
      description: 'Had a great time surfing in Santa Cruz', 
      tags: [ 'surfing', 'Santa Cruz', ], 
      categoryId: '22', 
    }, 
    status: {privacyStatus: 'private'} // Added; 
  };
  const newVideo = YouTube.Videos.insert( videoResource, "snippet,status", sourceFile); // Modified 
  console.log(newVideo) 
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here is the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert